# git rebase -i seems to have worked, but nothing has changed in the log

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm trying to reorder the commits in my master branch. I used following tutorial: http://blog.dennisrobinson.name/reorder-commits-with-git/

After saving my changes in the nano editor, the terminal says:

```
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

But when I type: `git log` nothing has changed.

I do not know if it matters, but I'm using Linux Mint 17.1

Comment: could you please post the full history of commands?

Comment: ... and the output of `git reflog` and `git reflog show master`.

Comment: Ok, now I try again with the same steps. The order of the commands I used was:
git rebase -i HEAD~4

Then on the nano editor I reorder commits cutting and pasting lines.
I saved the changes and left the nano to the terminal.

And surprise, it works! I can't figure out where I went wrong.

Anyway, sorry for the inconvenience.